# Problems with FTP uploads, files with acents

Tags: linux, upload, pureftpd

I am having problems with file uploads using pure-ftpd linux.

The files with acents, like Trovão.mp3 are renamed to TrovÃ£o.mp3 on upload.

How to prevent this?

Comment: What are client and server products that you're using? They may support the `opts utf-8 on` command. Or you may need to wrap the files in an archiver that preserves 8-bit chars in file names such as tar or zip.

Answer (score 0):

FTP supports only four transfer types: ASCII, EBCDIC, binary, and "local" (for 9-bit bytes, yes there are systems that have 9-bit bytes). UNICODE and UTF-8 are not supported. You will have to do the conversion yourself.